# How to edit a table in Internet Explorer 5 without innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, html-table

I'm trying to make a barcode scanner and I have a problem when some product doesn't exist it creates a new array with JavaScript and sends the problem to the that table. My problem is that I can't edit the table with `innerHTML`

JavaScript Function:

```
var table = document.getElementById("listViewTable");
var tableF = document.getElementById("listTable");
var rowCount = table.rows.length;
var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
var td1 = document.createElement("td");

//row.innerHTML = '(A few <td> and an <input>)';

td1.innerHTML = '(More <td> and another <input>)';
row.appendChild(td1);
row.className = "tableCell newSKU";
```

That commented line `row.innerhtml` is what I tried to achieve but I.E does not support it.

This should be the end result:

[image: Screenshot of table]

The last product in yellow can't be put in the same table and as such does not have the same style as the others.

Comment: Maybe you can take a look on tabular [XML data islands](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/bind-html-data-elements-to-xml-data-islands/)

Answer (score 3):

From [ppk's guide to browser quirks](http://quirksmode.org/dom/html/):

> In IE9 and lower `innerHTML` refuses to work on tables and selects. Solve this by using pure DOM methods instead. See [this explanation](http://www.ericvasilik.com/2006/07/code-karma.html) of the table behaviour by `innerHTML`’s inventor. I assume something similar goes for selects.

Use [`createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement), [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) and friends to create the cells.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal — An extensive list of every DOM method would be impractical.

Comment: Got it! Didn't listen the word `friends` for javascript.

Comment: @Kyll Its not necessary to delete the comments as keeping comments will be helpful for future readers as well.